# Remove focus on twitter bootstrap drown after selecting the option

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to focusout on bootstrap dropdown menu

after i select the option from the dropdown, the focus needs to be removed(blue border needs to be removed and also the focus on the dropdown menu)

when i use `command` button in my Mac machine, the dropdown list opens.

i tried with the following

```
<select class="list selectpicker" id="listing">
<option value="" selected="selected">All months</option>
<option value="7125">Aug</option>
<option value="2925">Nov</option>
<option value="2">Dec</option>
<option value="7119">Jan</opt

$("#listing").change(function(){
  $(this).blur();
});

css:
 .bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
  outline-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2jq4mLoj/13)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the focus to another element instead. Just add an empty "A" tag after the select and set focus to it on change.

```
<select class="list selectpicker" id="listing">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
<a id="a" href="#"></a>

$("#listing").selectpicker();
$("#listing").change(function(){
    $('#a').focus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Evoluteur/2jq4mLoj/35/